# glut game is not capturable by fraps or dxtory

Tags: opengl, glut, record, freeglut

I wanted to make some recordings of my game which uses an OpenGL window created by freeglut. The window or its gl-context seems to be unfindable for a recording applications like fraps, taksi or dxtory. How can I fix this?

Comment: The only thing I can think of is running gDEBugger and inspecting contexts directly.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz that looks neat. So you think of comparing mine with recordable OpenGL-applications to find the missing setting?

Comment: Yea, and also there's an option to show values different from defaults. Maybe your library changed something essential to these applications.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz It's very difficult to find out. I found the comparing function but nothing obvious for me.

Comment: Are you using double buffering? I'm not sure that these programs would be able to capture your window if you aren't.

Comment: I initialize glut with GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA